# Grails & spring security getting the id of the current logged in user

Tags: grails, spring-security

This is a sample code for the getCurrentUser() method in Spring Security service.

```
class SomeController {
    def springSecurityService

    def someAction() {
    def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
   }
}
```

How do you get the id of the logged in user and use it in this `<g:link action="show" controller="User" id="">Show Profile</g:link>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it's available in the "principal", which is an instance of `GrailsUser`, so the most efficient way is `springSecurityService.principal.id`

Answer (score 1):

In controller:

```
springSecurityService.currentUser.id
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work `<g:link action="show" controller="User" id="springSecurityService.currentUser.id">Show Profile</g:link>` and i already have this `def springSecurityService` in my controller

Comment: @MuduM This code has to be in controller, not GSP. Services are not injected in GSPs of course. In controller you have to add resulting id to the model and then you can use it in GSP

Comment: This is a very inefficient way to do this. The `getCurrentUser()` method goes to the database using in-memory information stored in the `Authentication`, and having done that you get the instance's id. But it was already there in memory without wasting a database call. See my answer.